# Auto-position divs side-by-side

Tags: html, css

I have some auto-generated HTML code.

When I add a `float:left;` on the shared class, it looks like this:

```
+----------------+   +--------------+
|   div 1        |   |   div 2      |
|                |   |              |
|                |   +--------------+
|                |                  
|                |   +--------------+
|                |   |   div 3      |
+----------------+   +--------------+
```

And what I want is this:

```
+----------------+   +--------------+
|   div 1        |   |   div 2      |
|                |   |              |
|                |   +--------------+
|                |                  
|                |   
|                |   
+----------------+   

+--------------+
|   div 3      |
+--------------+
```

How can I get this result?

My CSS code looks like this:

```
position: relative;
width: 40%;
float: left;
border: 1px solid black;
clear: left;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your divs have a common class name, such as `.boxes`, add this CSS:

```
.boxes:nth-child(odd) {clear: left;}
```

This will make it so that every odd-numbered box will clear the float and start a new line.

Alternatively, set the width of the container such that only two boxes will fit side-by-side, and then use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left;`.

Comment: The worst part is, I originally typed `2n+1` before I remembered the `odd/even` keywords.

Comment: I went for the display: inline-block; due to the minimum of code ^^

Answer (score 1):

just add `clear: left;` to the div 3

**EDIT:** simply use the `:nth-child(2n+1)` or `:nth-of-type(2n+1)` css3 selectors

Comment: The problem is that there can be generated more than three divs. and I want them to be under each other in two's

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard - updated the answer for you: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#structural-pseudos

Answer (score 0):

Add an element with the CSS property of clear:both; after the 2nd DIV, something like:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<br class="clear_both" />
<div id="third"></div>
```

Then in the CSS:

```
.clear_both {
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    width:0;
}
```